# Hide specific calendars from Notification Center

Tags: ios, calendar, notifications

I currently have five Calendar events displaying in Notification Center at a time. However, I have one specific calendar that I'd like to hide from it, as it has too many events for the Calendar-in-Notification-Center setup to be useful. As far as I've been able to surmise from my tinkering in settings, there's no way to do this. Has anyone else been able to find one?

Comment: I heard several complaints about it on the internet. There's no known solution right know. I hope Apple will listen to our prayers and fix this odd behavior (if I hide a calendar in Calendar.app for what strange reason would I like to see it in the notification center?!) with a 5.x update.

Comment: Where do your calendars live? Would you be amenable to a solution that requires setting up a second iCloud account to host the problematic calendar and having your primary account simply subscribe to the calendar?

Comment: @bmike The majority of them I don't own; they're subscriptions of family members' accounts through Google Calendar.

Comment: @bmike Though I see what you're getting at; you should submit it as an answer so the general public can see it. I won't accept it, but it might be helpful to others. :)

Comment: I'll leave it unanswered since I'm not answering it as asked, but suggesting a pretty big workaround. The site promotes unanswered questions and I don't want to rob you of that status without even a legitimate answer ;-)

Comment: Same applies to a lot of things, there are no granular controls for most Notification Centre apps.  I have iCloud and Exchange accounts on my phone, I only want personal alerts from my iCloud, but no can do at present.  I expect it will come.  Meanwhile, I have provided an answer with a useful workaround.

Comment: @bmike What about creating another Google account and using that to subscribe to the problem calendars? Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a 3rd party calendar app just for their notification functions as a bodgy workaround.

I recommend Calvetiva, Agenda, or Tempus.

The workflow would go something like this:

1. Choose a secondary calendar app.
2. Configure you secondary calendar app to only use the calendars you want alerts for (steps vary on choice of app). Some (like Calvetica) are clever, and extend the alerts function by allowing a snooze option etc.
3. Configure secondary calendar alerts and notifications via the normal settings> notifications app to show as you want them.  They will only trigger for the active calendars in the app.
4. Configure your normal calendar alerts to be off.  Remove from Notification Centre, set alert style to none, and also go onto Sounds > alerts and set the calendar alert to none.

Now your existing calendar app will still have access to all calendars but won't alert, the secondary app will do alerting only for the active ones.

Downsides:  You will need to periodically open and then shut the secondary calendar every so often in order for it to read the current alerts from the calendar data store and create it's own local notifications from them.

I hoped you could get round this by following the above steps but using the built in calendar as your selective alerting calendar (as it is always running and won't need to be opened to update), and using a replacement calendar app with all calendars shown but no alerts - sadly the normal Calendar app includes all calendars regardless of if you have turned a calendar off or not.

Comment: That's a good idea, and it's what I've decided is probably the best option. +1, but I'm not marking it as correct because it *is* a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, unless Apple changes something, this is as close to a correct answer as we're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

On my jailbroken iPhone, I make use of [LockInfo](http://www.lockinfo.net/).
With LockInfo, you not only get notification center on the lock screen, you have more control over what notification center does.

And relating directly to your question, with this plugin, you can navigate to:
System Settings -> LockInfo -> Notifications and Widgets -> Calendar -> Calendars; and select which appear.

Comment: To the downvoter, I would point out that this was a relevant solution prior to iOS 7 being released...

Comment: I would like to chip in here on the downvoters side, we don't usually accept jailbreaking devices as a viable solution to a problem. Apart from it not being liked by Apple, but at this very moment, you can't jailbreak your device if it's updated. So what good is this solution?

Answer (score 0):

This app can do exactly what is needed here : you can choose which calendars to display on its Notification Center widget !

[Agenda+ | Calendar & Reminder Widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/agenda+-calendar-reminder/id916415258?mt=8)

It also displays all day events.