# How do I limit calendar notifications to certain calendars?

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications

In Calendar, I have a number of "iCloud" calendars that I share with my wife.  ("Family", "Me", "Her", etc.) so we can see when we're both free/busy.

While I do want to see her whole schedule on my calender, I don't necessarily want a pop-up notification every time she has a surgery. (I'm not a bad husband; she's a surgeon.)

Is there some way to set different notification settings for individual calendars *within a calendar account* (in this case, iCloud)?

Comment: Possible duplicate (of): [Hide specific calendars from Notification Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28151/14994)

Comment: Not a duplicate: this is about Mac OS X; the linked question is about iOS.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Calendar.app, you can right-click on any calendar, and choose **Get Info**. From here you can select **Ignore Alerts**

Comment: I don't know how I missed this when it came in, but it's huge!

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac side, I solved this by using BusyCal 2.

1. In System Preferences "Notifications", turn off all Notifications for both Calendar
   and BusyCal
2. In BusyCal Preferences, under "Alarms", turn on "Show Alarms" and
   select "use BusyCal Alarm window".
3. In BusyCal select the offending calendar(s), and "Get Info" under the
   "Edit" menu.  In the popup window under "Subscribe Options", select "Ignore Alarms".

I'm using iCloud and I much prefer the Alarms dialog under BusyCal to the systems notification center.

There is a 30-day demo of BusyCal for testing and the app is on "sale" until 12/31/2012.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, it seems that there is no solution at this time.  Over four pages of reports on discussions.apple.com and it seems that iCloud is broken for notifications in this manner on iOS.

The people it affect most is married couples.  Ha.  One possible solution involves calling Apple support.  If you read through you will see on Oct 17th the person who was having the issue got a call back from Apple and they reset their Apple account.  Many people are complaining that the option to save isn't working right now, it is a bug, apparently.

You can try to call and see if that will work.  Good luck.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4339714?start=0&tstart=0
Here is a resolution from the discussions thread.

> Through iCloud.com -> Calendar -> Preferences -> Event Updates: the ability to 
>   tick/untick "Email me shared calendar updates" seems to save now when I log out and > log back in (that setting never used to hold). I have now turned this off for my 
>   partner and he no longer receives email notifications (although it does still appear > in the Invitations tray on the iPhone Calendar app which is annoying).
>
> My partner and I also share Reminder lists (a grocery shopping one, jobs on our home > reno etc) and after the iOS6 update on our iPhone's we lost the ability to
>   share/unshare these lists. Through iCloud.com -> Reminders you can now hover to the > right of the list name and a share icon is revealed where you can share/unshare the > reminder list with someone. Since iOS6 we also started receiving email notifications > everytime something was added to a shared reminder list (ie. Tomatoes) which was 
>   effing annoying. This seems to have stopped =)